# I get a javascript code stored in string format want to convert to pure javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

suppose i have a  variable in string format for example and i have a javascript code in that

```
 var string="function myFunction(a,b){return a*b;}";
```

this i want to convert into pure javascript code format as

```
function myFunction(a, b) {
return a * b;
}
```

how to do this? i mean i am getting the javascript code in string complete  format but i want to convert that to pure javascript code, its like beautifing the code which is in string format what should i do, and is their any way to do it in angular,javascript or c#

Comment: You mean, eval()?...

Comment: What made you do this ?

Comment: This is a clear case of an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: You could use js-beautify to format your javascript code if that is what you are after, see https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify

Comment: Both code blocks in your question are invalid (did you try running them?)...

Comment: @ThiefMaster i did'nt run the code, yes that was only for an example, and i have modified that now

Comment: @RayonDabre i actual rendering the code to ui-ace javascipt editor that was already saved

Comment: thanks but  i get the javascript code into string format and i just want to render it on ui-ac editor so thats way i am converting it to javascrip code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var string="function sum(){return 'sum'}";
eval(string);
```

then you could call sum() as you want.

Comment: thanks mark but i dont want to call sum() actually i get the javascript code into string format and i just want to render it on ui-ac editor so thats way i am converting it to javascrip code

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a `function` too. Example:

```
var func ="sum(a,b){return a+b}";   

var F=new function (func);

F();
```